# Synchronize data 2 times per day in Android

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I have a server which stores dynamically changing data. My app after launching is connecting to the server and gets this data but I'm updating it manually. So I need to automatically synchronize server and get updated data at least 2 times per day. Any suggestions how to do it?

P.S. I'm getting data from server in json format using gson google lib.

P.P.S. As I understood I need to use Sync Adapter but I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) when you first start your application, register your Alarm Manager to fire setting the "repeat" flag to 12 hours. Then register a [receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for that alarm, and when the Broadcast Receiver recives the intent, make it start a service that handles your server connection.